# Load a Page to a certain div position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically, what I have is a page with multiple div objects that take up 100vh.

```
<div id="one">blah blah blah</div>
<div id="two">blah blah blah</div>
<div id="three">blah blah blah</div>
```

How can I load the page to start on #two so I can scroll up to #one later?

EDIT: I cannot simply amend the URL with a hash location; this needs to be done through the base url.

Comment: www.example.com/#two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try a function as so using the html you have.

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('two').scrollIntoView();
};
```

You don't have to change your divs into links, this method works for all sorts of divs.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView

Comment: I'm trying this. And it works!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash navigation. It uses the following syntax :

```
page url#id of the element to be scrolled to
```

So, basically you append `#two` to your url on page load using:

`location.hash = "two";`

And then in html you can have this:

```
<a href="#one">Click me to go to one</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an option: the requrement is someone going to the base URL being loaded to the second position.